# Is there a way to get a range of records in Postgres using LIMIT keyword

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I have a table with a count column, I want to get batches of the records in the table base don the value of count. Note the count field is not a unique id - there maybe many rows with the same count.

I can use this query to get the 30000 records with the highest count

```
select *
from artist t1
order by count desc
LIMIT 30000;
```

but is there a way to get a range, i.e records 30001 to 60000, records 60001 to 90000 ect.

Comment: With a range is it still ordered by the highest count?

Comment: No problem, see my answer using `OFFSET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OFFSET` function.

First 30000:

```
SELECT *
FROM artist t1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 30000;
```

30001 to 60000

```
SELECT *
FROM artist t1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 30000 OFFSET 30001;
```

60001 to 90000

```
SELECT *
FROM artist t1
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 30000 OFFSET 60001;
```

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed